# Access Vue instance in export const

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm making a multifile Vue application, obviously I'm working with exports and my instance is created in a different file than the export. I'd like to know how I can use `this`.$storage properly.

Here's my setup:

app.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import store from '~/store'
import Vue2Storage from 'vue2-storage'

Vue.use(Vue2Storage, {
    prefix: 'app_',
    driver: 'local',
    ttl: 60 * 60 * 1000
})

app = new Vue({
    mixins: [..instance created here..],
    store
})
```

store/index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

// Load store modules dynamically.
const requireContext = require.context('./modules', false, /.*\.js$/)

const modules = requireContext.keys()
    .map(file =>
        [file.replace(/(^.\/)|(\.js$)/g, ''), requireContext(file)]
    )
    .reduce((modules, [name, module]) => {
        if (module.namespaced === undefined) {
        module.namespaced = true
        }

        return { ...modules, [name]: module }
    }, {})

export default new Vuex.Store({
    modules
})
```

store/modules/exchange.js

```
...

export const actions = {
    getExchanges ({ commit, dispatch }) {
        if (this.$storage.has('exchange.list')) {
        return this.$storage.get('exchange.list')
        } else {
        return Trade.getExchanges()
            .then(exchanges => {
            commit(types.SET_EXCHANGES, exchanges)
            })
            .catch(error => console.error(error))
        }
    }
}

...
```

Comment: do you mean `this.$store` (which should work with your code) or `this.$storage` for which you would have to add `storage:...` to your `new Vue(` instantiation

Comment: Once you call `Vue.use(Vue2Storage, ...)` (as you've done in `app.js`), the `$storage` property is available on your Vue instance, allowing you to use the [`vue2-storage` API](https://yarkovaleksei.github.io/vue2-storage/en/api.html) via `this.$storage` from any Vue instance.

Comment: It's indeed the `this.$storage` which is called inside `this.$store` - however because it's in an export const I did not have access to `this` and had to use `this._vm` instead to access `$storage`